# Server-side form validation AJAX by comparing two textboxes on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create some very simple server side form validation using ajax, to check if the data a user has entered is equal to data I have on another page.

So for example, a user enters the number 10 in a textbox (#TextBox1) and then submits this; ajax should then check if this number matches the number I have in a textbox (#TextBox2) on another page and return the relevant information.

Currently my code returns false, but is this actually possible?

Here's some code I've been playing with:

```
<!-- Page 1 -->

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myvalidationpage.aspx",
    data: '{number: "' + $("#TextBox1").val() + '" }',
    success: function (n) {
        if(n === $("#TextBox2").val()){
            alert("true");
        }else{
            alert("false");
        }
    }
});
</script>

<!-- Page 2 (/myvalidationpage.aspx) -->
<input type="text" value="10" id="TextBox2" name="TextBox2" />
```

Comment: Use 'sessions' to store and use data across pages

Comment: yes, you must store in session somehow, or save in db, and check against the db value. This code, (n === $("#TextBox2").val()), will always be false as it compares the result of the ajax request against an element not on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot check values on the page without it being sent to the server.

One possible solution would be to send the information from the first page, and save it in a session variable. Then once on the next page, trigger a function that asks the session if it is the same number or not.

Another solution would be to use cookies to store the information from page one, and check it on page 2.

If you are marketing towards newer browsers, you can use HTML5's local storage mechanism. This is very similar to storing information in cookies, but I believe it cannot be turned off.

I think there would be the three easiest solutions to implement.